# Render output corrupted on Google Chrome

Tags: mac, google-chrome

Any ideas why this is happening with Google Chrome?

[image: chrome break screen]

Answer (score 8):

Your screenshots are displaying repeating patterns of video artifacts which are characteristic of [video RAM artifacts](http://www.playtool.com/pages/artifacts/artifacts.html).

If your computer screen is displaying video RAM artifacts, then it would show up first in Google Chrome because Google Chrome uses a lot of RAM. Chrome splits every tab, plugin, and extension into its own process, so that if one thing crashes it doesn’t bring down the whole webpage. Chrome’s prerendering feature can also cause higher memory usage.

If the RAM in your graphics card is failing, sometimes just a small fraction of the RAM goes bad while the rest of the RAM continues to work properly. This can result in a screen that looks like a fraction of the screen has glitchy repeating patterns of video artifacts, while the rest of the screen is rendered properly. As a workaround in Chrome, browse to *Settings* -> *Show advanced settings...* -> scroll down to the *System* heading and uncheck the checkbox to the left of *Use hardware acceleration when available*.

Hardware acceleration in Chrome can also be temporarily disabled from the command line in OS X by starting Chrome using the `--disable-gpu` Google Chrome command line switch as follows:

```
open -a "Google Chrome" --args --disable-gpu
```

Comment: I would've never had the answer for why only _part_ of Chrome was displaying artifacts. +1 for covering all bases

Comment: I wonder if hardware accelerated rendering might play a part.

Comment: @karel, >>As a workaround in Chrome, browse to Settings ->.  
It's impossible, because _all_ Chrome looks like this.

Comment: @karel, well, i tried `open -a "Google Chrome" --args --disable-gpu `. Same thing, still not working.

Comment: I don't think this will work either in your Chrome web browser, but as a reference you can find other command line switches that contain the string `gpu` at this website: http://peter.sh/experiments/chromium-command-line-switches/

Comment: Hmm, disabling hardware acceleration fixed it for me.

Comment: Interesting that many are seeing the same issue at the same time however - seems surprising that all of our VRAM has gotten simultaneously corrupted - http://superuser.com/questions/986618/what-happened-to-my-chrome-browser

Comment: This happened to me, make sure you shutdown Chrome completely (not just close the window) before running `open -a "Google Chrome" --args --disable-gpu` otherwise it looks like it just creates a window using the Chrome that's running.