# What happened to my chrome browser?

Tags: macos, google-chrome

Today something weird happened to my Chrome browser. It started showing like this

[image]

I'm using a OSX Yosmite running on a virtual machine. It worked great for years but something happened Today and I'm uncertain what's that.

I tried to install it again but problem persists.

Is anyone familiar with this?

Comment: This question looks an awful lot like [this other one asked eight hours ago](http://superuser.com/q/986421/83694).  Perhaps there was a regression introduced in [the new Google Chrome 46](http://googlechromereleases.blogspot.com/2015/10/stable-channel-update.html).

Comment: It looks very similar indeed. Since this happened suddenly, a browser update would explain this very well. I tested solution proposed there but had no luck :(. Thanks

Comment: Have you tried rolling back to version 45?

Comment: @DavidPostill: how can I do that?

Comment: Download and install the previous version?

Comment: @I thought there was built in feature on browser to rollback to previous versión. I'll have to disable automatic updates since otherwise it will upgrade to latest versión automatically

Comment: [How to Revert to Older Versions of Firefox and Chrome](http://www.technorms.com/30164/revert-to-older-versions-of-firefox-chrome-browser)

Comment: https://www.chromium.org/administrators/frequently-asked-questions - Can I roll back Google Chrome to a previous version?

    No - rollback is not supported.

    To get to a previous version (which would not be supported by Google), you would need to uninstall your current version, delete every user's saved profile data, and re-install the older version.  
    This means users will lose their bookmarks, history, etc., so use this method with extreme caution.

Comment: Chrome **OS** has a rollback feature, not the browser.