# Display looks corrupted/broken black blocks

Tags: display, graphics-card

[Video demonstration](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JWrflFi0UwY)  of issue.

hardware:

CPU: amd fx 6300

GPU: nvidia gtx 560 ti

What could be the problem ?

I don't have onboard video on this motherboard to test with it. Didn't install/mess with any firmware. Tried with different monitor, same issue.

Comment: It looks like it could be caused by broken graphics card RAM: [Render output corrupted on Google Chrome](http://superuser.com/questions/986421/render-output-corrupted-on-google-chrome). Try testing your Nvidia GTX 560 graphics card by putting it in another computer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's clearly a hardware issue.

The way the display is corrupted points to corruption of the GDDR5 RAM. This can be for several reasons: Overheating, dead RAM, dead capacitors in the on-board DC/DC converter or, in my opinion most likely, cracks in the balls of the nVidia BGA chip.

Check the temperature of the components, visually inspect the capacitors, if you have the equipment, then measure them, and if everything looks fine, I'd try a reflow of the BGA. (Google for how its done).

But unless you really enjoy tinkering, simply buying a new graphics adapter will be the most cost efficient way of solving the issue.

Answer (score 1):

Alright, things are getting serious.

As always, proceed step by step (might seems dumb, but most of the time you can solve 90% of these problems) :

1) Try with another screen using another type of connector (HDMI/DVI/VGA/Display Port..)

2) Try with another cable.

3) Make sure the cable is correctly inserted both ends

4) Check whether dust/dirt is inside the port or on the connectors (already happened to me)

5) Update driver if available. Do not use beta drivers. Use the latest stable version.

6) Check if the GPU is overheating. Look for damaged pins. Try with another GPU if available to make sure the issue comes from the GPU alone.

Once all of this is clear, then we can pursue the diagnosis

Comment: tried with different display and other cables/interfaces. problem is the gpu. How can driver be the problem if display is messed up right from the POST screen? I let it cool down and then started it, the first thing I see is a corrupted display. I doubt this is heating.

Comment: Then buy another GPU, problem solved. Send previous oin to warranty if not expired

Comment: Why would the driver be the problem if it happens right on the POST screen which certainly uses text mode from the BIOS?! Also the GRUB screen is text too and again, no driver...